# Evaluate $\int \sqrt {3 \tan^2 \theta - 1} d \theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $I=\int \sqrt {3  \tan^2 \theta - 1} d \theta$

My attempt
$\tan \theta = t, $ then $I = \int \frac{\sqrt {3t^2-1}}{1+t^2} dt   $

Now integrating by parts,

I = $\sqrt {3t^2-1} \tan^{-1} t- \int( \frac{6t}{2\sqrt {(3t^2-1)}} \tan^{-1} t) dt$

Now i am struck... How to proceed.

Comment: oh my God it's horrible lol http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Csqrt+%7B3+%5Ctan%5E2+%5Ctheta+-+1%7D+d+%5Ctheta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints :

$$=\int \frac {(2\tan \theta\sec^2\theta)(\sqrt {3\tan ^2\theta-1})}{(2\tan \theta\sec^2\theta)} d\theta$$

Let $$\tan^2\theta=\frac {x^2+1}{3}$$ hence $$2\tan \theta\sec^2\theta=2x/3$$

And then change the integral to $$\sqrt 3\int \frac {x^2}{(x^2+4)\sqrt {x^2+1}}dx= \sqrt 3\int \frac {1}{\sqrt {x^2+1}}dx-4\sqrt 3\int \frac {1}{(x^2+4)\sqrt {x^2+1}}dx$$

Evaluate the first integral using the substitution $x=\tan \alpha$ and end the second one with the substitution $x=\frac 1t$ which further can be evaluated by the substitution $$t^2+1=u^2$$

Comment: thank you. Good one.

Comment: @Magneto you're welcome

Comment: How does substituting $x=\dfrac 1t$ help to solve the second integral ?

Comment: @DarkKnight $$\int\frac {1}{(x^2+4)\sqrt {x^2+1}}dx=-\int \frac {t}{(4t^2+1)\sqrt {t^2+1}}dt$$ with substitution $$t^2+1=u^2$$ we get $$-\int \frac {t}{(4t^2+1)\sqrt {t^2+1}}dt=-\int \frac {1}{4u^2-3} du$$ Which can be solved easily by partial fractions. You must have tried the substitution a little bit before downvoting the answer

Comment: @Manthanein Can't help with the downvote. PSE effect. If you edit the answer a little bit, I can remove the downvote. No offence intended.

Comment: @DarkKnight Edit done

Answer (score 5):

The result of @Manthanein can be obtained without much difficulty.

The integral can also be written as $$\int \sqrt{3\sec^2 \theta -4} \, \mathrm d\theta$$

Now, substitute $$\begin{align}3\sec^2 \theta -4 &=x^2\\ \implies 3\sec^2 \theta \tan \theta \, \mathrm d\theta &= x \, \mathrm dx \\ \implies (x^2+4)\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}3}\,\mathrm d\theta &=x\,\mathrm dx \\ \implies \mathrm d\theta &=\dfrac{\sqrt 3 x\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2+4)\sqrt{x^2+1}}\end{align}$$

Hence the integral now becomes $$\int\dfrac{\sqrt3 x^2 \mathrm dx}{(x^2+4)\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

and the rest follows.

Comment: How is this in anyway simple than my way?

Comment: @Manthanein You multiplied the numerator and the denominator of the integrand by $2\tan \theta \sec^2 \theta$ which doesn't come naturally. What I did was I simply expressed $\tan^2 \theta$ in terms of $\sec^2 \theta$ and made the substitution which is pretty straightforward.